# Angular v15 Ag-Grid Server Side Row Model (SSRM) not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to switch our ag-grid implementation from client-side to server-side and I'm running into issues populating the row data to the grid. I'm able to load my column definitions that I'm getting back from a service call response. I'm also getting a successful response for the data to populate the rows, but the row data will not display in the grid. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Angular Version:**

```
"@angular/core": "15.2.9",
```

**Ag-Grid Version:**

```
"@ag-grid-community/angular": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-community/core": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/filter-tool-panel": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/range-selection": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter": "^29.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/side-bar": "^29.2.0",
```

**Grid Options:**

```
export const GridDefaultSetting: GridOptions = {
    rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    cacheBlockSize: 50,
    maxBlocksInCache: 2,
    floatingFiltersHeight: 47,
    headerHeight: 47,
    multiSortKey: 'ctrl',
    rowHeight: 47,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    suppressCellSelection: false,
    suppressContextMenu: true,
    suppressRowClickSelection: true,
    unSortIcon: true,
    pagination: true,
    paginationAutoPageSize: false,
    suppressPaginationPanel: false,
    debug: true,
    defaultColDef: {
        sortingOrder: ['asc', 'desc'],
        resizable: false,
    },
    animateRows: false,
    suppressColumnMoveAnimation: true,
    components: {
        renderDate: RenderDateComponent,
        renderIcon: RenderIconComponent,
        renderLink: RenderLinkComponent,
        renderAction: RenderActionComponent,
        renderDNC: RenderDncComponent,
        renderTime: RenderTimeComponent,
        renderTaskStatus: RenderTaskStatusComponent,
        customDatePicker: CustomDatePickerComponent,
        customDropDown: CustomDropdownFilterComponent,
        customLoadingOverlay: CustomOverlayComponent,
        customTextFilter: CustomTextFilterComponent,
        customMultiSelectFilter: CustomMultiSelectFilterComponent,
        openRapidApp: StartRapidAppComponent,
        viewSourceDetails: SourceDetailsComponent,
        customDetailRenderer: DetailRendererComponent,
        renderStatusIcons: RenderStatusIconsComponent,
        renderLock: RenderLockComponent,
    },
    loadingOverlayComponent: 'customLoadingOverlay',
};
```

**HTML View:**

```
<ag-grid-angular #mainGrid
  class="workqueue ag-theme-material"
  [class.ag__shrink]="isImpersonationOn"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [modules]="modules"
  [masterDetail]="false"
  [detailRowAutoHeight]="false"
  [accentedSort]="true"
  [sideBar]="false"
  [serverSideInfiniteScroll]="false"
  [rowBuffer]="0"
  (rowGroupOpened)="rowOpened($event)"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (sortChanged)="onSortChanged()"
  (filterChanged)="onFilterChanged()"
  (filterModified)="onFilterModified($event)"
  (rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged()"
  (columnVisible)="onColumnsChanged($event)"
  (dragStarted)="dragStarted()"
  (columnMoved)="onColumnDrag()"
  (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectedRows()">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**On Grid Ready**

```
public onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<any>): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.workqueueService.setGridApi(this.gridApi);
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.sortFilterInfo = undefined;
    this.gridReady = true;
    this.activePage = 1;

    if (this.currentQueue) {
        this.isSelectable(this.router.url.split('/')[1] === 'tasks');
        this.loadGridData(this.currentQueue);
        this.setSaveFilterAction.emit(false);
        this.resetFilterList();
        this.setSortAndFilter();
        this.addGridEventListeners();
        this.gridApi.redrawRows();
    }
}
```

**Load Grid Data**

```
private loadGridData(data: WorkqueueResponse): void {
    /* 
    * NOTE: Doing a bunch of stuff in here
    */

    this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(this.createServerDatasource());
}
```

**Create Server Data Source**

```
private createServerDatasource(): IServerSideDatasource {
    return {
        getRows: params => {
            const request: GetPaginatedWqDataRequest = {
                userId: this.userId,
                viewListId: 3,
                viewType: this.viewType ?? 'deal',
                pageNumber: 1,
                pageSize: 50,
            };

            this.workqueueService.getPaginatedWorkqueueData(request).subscribe({
                next: resp => {
                    this.rowData = resp.data;

                    params.success({
                        rowData: resp.data,
                        rowCount: resp.totalCount,
                    });
                },
                error: () => params.fail(),
            });
        },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are setting the datasource after gridOptions are already set, in an async callback method, is suspect. Is it possible that the Angular framework is not aware of the grid component state change because it's happening outside of a normal change detection cycle?

Try injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` into your class and calling `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in your loadGridData() method and see if this solves your issue.

You might also try setting the datasource in the initial `gridOptions` instead of setting it in your `loadGridData` callback. If you need to wait for the callback before you can load data, you can use `RxJs` observable pipelines in your `getRows` method to handle this wait. If you don't have an Observable to start with, consider using a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` and update it in your `loadGridData` method.

If these steps don't solve your problem, please provide a minimal example project that reproduces the issue.